# Slow artifact downloads from Team City

Tags: ruby, teamcity, wget

I'm trying to download the last successful build from TeamCity as part of our rake deployment script. The file is a zip file that is 8mb, and I get over http, using a url:

http://buildserver/guestAuth/repository/download/bt12/.lastSuccessful/Build.7z

If I open that url in Firefox, the zip file downloads in about 1-2 seconds. Basically instant.

However, it's taking ages.

1) I tried using the ruby HTTP:Net library. It would take around 1 minute and sometimes fail. I read that in 1.8.6 this lib wasn't very fast though, so decided to move on.

2) I tried wget, so can see the progress. It gets to about 6mb with a second or so, then just hangs. Then after a minute suddenly completes.

3) I tried Fiddlerv2 to get some more output. It gets to about 7.9mb then does exactly the same as wget, takes about a minute.

I'm guessing it's either gonna be the client, our network, or TeamCity's web server.

Given that Firefox works ok, the network seems sound. So I'm investigating options with wget to try and get it to work quickly.

Any ideas what it could be, or is it a known issue with TeamCity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, figured it out.

Was our network virus scanner kicking in!

Weird that wget would only get to about 75% though. Thought it would fully download it before scanning it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit odd, but try [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ruby/) anyway....

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how teamCity works, but it must have a webserver somewhere, when you put a file on it and try to download it via firefox, is it working ?